# What rule allows to determine the symbol on an $i$-th cell of the tape of an Infinite Time Turing Machine at any limit stage?

Tags: logic, ordinals, turing-machines

Assuming that $s$ denotes a particular symbol that can appear on the tape,  $\alpha$ denotes any limit ordinal such that $\alpha \ge \omega$ and $C_i[\tau]$ denotes the symbol on the $i$-th cell of the tape at stage $\tau$, I need an answer to the following question:

> given an arbitrary limit ordinal $\alpha$ and an arbitrary natural number $n$, what is $C_n[\alpha]$?

As far as I understand, the answer can be formulated as follows:

> $C_n[\alpha] = s$ if there exists an ordinal $\beta_1 < \alpha$ such that for any ordinal $\beta_2 > \beta_1$, the condition $C_n[\beta_2] = C_n[\beta_1] = s$ is true (assuming that $\beta_2 < \alpha$);
>
> $C_n[\alpha] = 1$ if an ordinal $\beta_1$ does not exist.

Is the above answer mathematically correct? Are there any missing details?

Comment: Yes, for cell values, the basic idea is right. To determine a cell value at given limit $\alpha$, one wants to check whether the value stablises (so to speak) at some point before $\alpha$ or not. If it does, then that "stablised value" is maintained at $\alpha$. However, if the cell value goes back to $0$ infinitely often (after going to $1$) in the limit $\alpha$ (I think the precise way of phrasing it is a bit different though) then the cell value is set to $1$ at $\alpha$.

Comment: Also, very briefly, what I wrote in previous comment is under "lim sup" rule/convention (so to speak). Under "lim inf" rule, if the cell value oscillates in the limit $\alpha$ (meaning it doesn't stabilise), then the cell value would be set to $0$ at $\alpha$.